# Only the article author can edit his/her own article ID

Tags: php

I have the *articles* table like this:

```
article_id      user_id     user_level     article         date
 1                1             1          bla bla         3/15/2014
 2                17            1          bla bla         3/16/2014
 3                5             1          bla bla         3/20/2014
```

- Assume that I can record user session by applying `$loggedinuser = isset($_SESSION[user_id`]);` as the user signs into the forum.
- Assume that I can get the `article_id` for both the normal internet viewers and the article's author when the article is browsed by using the conditional `if (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])){...}`. This will aim to *limit direct access* to the **edit.php** page, instead of **edit.php?id=1**, for example, of which the part `?id=1` is the `name=value pair` to the URL. I mean the `edit.php` page can only be accessed through another page, called **view_article.php**, which carries the hyperlink like `<a href="edit.php?id={$row['id']}`.

My problem is that I cannot **restrict** a specific user, for example `user_id # 1`, to **only** edit his own article, for example `article_id #1`, but he can edit any article if he manually changes the value pair part.

*Can you help me please?*

Note: 1/ I can only use procedural approach, not Object-Oriented Programming (OOP).

2/ All users have the same level, **which is 1**. I mean they are on the same level as normal users without any limitation (suspended accounts) or special privilege (admin).

Comment: uh, so why don't you just have the edit script check WHO's accessing the record and NOT let non-owners actually get the edit form? `if($article_owner != $current_user) { exit(); }`. boom. problem solved.

Comment: @MarcB +1 for boom :)

Comment: @MarcB: your piece of code was correct. However, if the `user's session's check` were matched, the *edit form* would be printed repeatedly because the `if conditional` is put inside the `WHILE loop`. And this makes me add some more codes. Furthermore, the `$current_user` does not need the `isset` function either. Thanks a lot!